# How to check a treeset contains at least one items from another treeset

Tags: java

I have a treeset contains user selected items and I am trying to check with another base treeset which contains all items. If the user-selected set contains at leaset one item from base treeset, I should return true.

Here is my code:

```
Set<String> baseItems = new TreeSet<String>Arrays.asList("HEALTH","SPORTS","GAMES","COURSE","FITNESS"));

Set<String> userItems = getRequestedItems();
// userItems has values like HEALTH,SPORTS

// if userItems contains or match with any items in the baseItems list it should return true.
boolean isMatch = requestedApiPillars.contains(apiPillars); // this returning class cast exception.
```

How do I compare userSet with baseItems to make sure they selected the specific items?

Comment: This code isn't valid Java code...it won't compile.  The first line is just wrong, and two critical variables on the last line have no definition.  But getting to your question anyway...I don't think there's a better way to do what you want than to iterate through `userItems`, looking to see if each item is in `baseItems`, and stopping when you find a match.  I don't know if there's a library method to do that, but I don't think you can do it any more efficiently than just doing it yourself through a simple iteration.

Comment: Simplest way is something like `set1.stream().anyMatch(set2::contains)`.

Comment: Thank you Steve , Iwill update the first line . how do I add values to baseItems?

Comment: @kaya3 I tried .stream() but my IDE is not showing stream method. The project I am working using old versio of java .

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Collections.disjoint()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#disjoint-java.util.Collection-java.util.Collection-):

```java
boolean isMatch = (! userItems.isEmpty()) && (! Collections.disjoint(baseItems, userItems));
```

Specifically, if at least one member of `baseItems` is also in `userItems`, the collections are not disjoint.